# PL/SQL Trigger with specific variable from update

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to trigger an update after an update.

My Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
  STUDENT_ID          INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME                CHAR(40)    NOT NULL,
  SURNAME             CHAR(40)    NOT NULL,
  TOKEN               CHAR(5)     NOT NULL,
  STUDYCOURSE         CHAR(20)    NOT NULL,
  NOTE                VARCHAR(255)    NULL,
  WARNING_ID          INTEGER     REFERENCES MAHNUNG (ID),
  BLOCKED             CHAR(1)     CHECK (Gesperrt IN('J', 'N'));

create table RENTAL (
  RENTAL_ID           INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
  RENTALDATE          DATE        DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  RENTALDURATION      INTEGER     NOT NULL,
  OVERDRAWN           CHAR(1)     CHECK (OVERDRAWN IN('Y', 'N'));
```

My Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OVERDRAWN_RETURN
AFTER UPDATE OF OVERDRAWN ON RENTAL
  REFERENCING OLD AS OLD AND NEW AS NEW

BEGIN
  IF :NEW.OVERDRAWN := 'Y' THEN
  UPDATE STUDENT SET WARNING_ID = WARNING_ID+1
  WHERE STUDENT.STUDENT_ID = RENTAL.STUDENT_ID;
  END IF;
END OVERDRAWN_RETURN;
/
```

What I'm basically trying to do is increment the WARNING_ID when OVERDRAWN is updated to 'Y' (yes). 
Error report -

```
ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification
04079. 00000 -  "invalid trigger specification"
*Cause:    The create TRIGGER statement is invalid.
*Action:   Check the statement for correct syntax.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: btw, you should use `VARCHAR2`, not `VARCHAR` or `CHAR`. Also, your caps lock is on ;)

Answer (score 1):

you were using assignment operator(:=) in IF statement.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OVERDRAWN_RETURN
    AFTER UPDATE OF OVERDRAWN ON RENTAL
      REFERENCING OLD AS OLD AND NEW AS NEW

    BEGIN
      IF :NEW.OVERDRAWN = 'Y' THEN
      UPDATE STUDENT SET WARNING_ID = WARNING_ID+1
      WHERE STUDENT.STUDENT_ID = RENTAL.STUDENT_ID;
      END IF;
    END OVERDRAWN_RETURN;
    /
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as the use of `:=` instead of `=`for comparison that @Prashant pointed out, there are some other issues. The actual error you see is because of the `REFERENCING` line, which should not have the `AND`.

But you can't use new and old for statement triggers, so you need to make it a `FOR EACH ROW` trigger too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OVERDRAWN_RETURN
AFTER UPDATE OF OVERDRAWN ON RENTAL
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  IF :NEW.OVERDRAWN = 'Y' THEN
    UPDATE STUDENT SET WARNING_ID = WARNING_ID+1
    WHERE STUDENT_ID = :NEW.STUDENT_ID;
  END IF;
END OVERDRAWN_RETURN;
/
```

You were referring to `RENTAL.STUDENT_ID`, but that is out of scope for the SQL statement. So I've changed that to refer to the current row, with `:NEW.STUDENT_ID`. But either way, your `RENTAL` table doesn't have a `STUDENT_ID` column, but you may have just omitted that when editing the definition for posting.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I inserted STUDENT_ID via ALTER TABLE command and forgot to insert it directly into my table. So is :NEW.STUDENT_ID referring to the updated row of RENTAL above?

Comment: @HandsomeJane - yes, referring to `:NEW.xxx` means the new value of `xxx` in the affected row the trigger fired against. [Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955). If the update statement had changed `STUDENT_ID` then `:OLD.STUDENT_ID` would be the old value last set in that row in the table, and `:NEW.STUDENT_ID` would be the new value supplied in the update statement, and what the table row will contain after the update completes. In this case you probably aren't expecting it to change.